# How to make boundaries work in turtle - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So, I was making a game in which I need to move a player which is just a square as of now but it can go out of the screen if I keep pressing the key. I want to stop the player at the end of the screen.
Here is my code this is not the complete game:

```
import turtle
sc=turtle.Screen()
sc.title("Math fighter")
sc.bgcolor("black")
sc.setup(width=1000, height=600)
player=turtle.Turtle()
player.speed(0)
player.shape("square")
player.color("white")
player.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=3)
player.penup()
player.goto(0, -250)
def playerleft():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= 20
    player.setx(x)


def playerright():
    y = player.xcor()
    y += 20
    player.setx(y)
sc.listen()
sc.onkeypress(playerright, "Right")
sc.onkeypress(playerleft, "Left")
```

Comment: you don't use PyGame so I removed tag `pygame`

Comment: you have to use `if/else` to check position before `player.setx(...)` and skip it. That's all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only use `if` to check position before `setx()` and skip it. That's all.

```
def playerleft():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= 20

    if x > -500:
        player.setx(x)


def playerright():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += 20

    if x < 500:
       player.setx(x)
```